# How to scroll after render in React?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am trying to make an accordion component that is similar to the `<details><summary>` HTML elements.

I want to make my own component because I want to use `useState()` to control whether my accordion is open or not.

First I tried this:

```
const WeirdAlAccordion: React.FC<MyProps> = ({
  children,
}: MyProps) => {
  const scrollingRef = useRef(null);
  const [isToggleOpen, setIsToggleOpen] = useState(false);

  const scrollMyRef = () => {
    // Only scroll into view if it is being opened.
    if (!isToggleOpen) {
      scrollingRef.current.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="my-id" ref={scrollingRef}>
        <IonItem>
          <HandednessToggle
            checked={isToggleOpen}
            onClick={() => {
              setIsToggleOpen(!isToggleOpen);
              scrollMyRef();
            }}
            label={"My Label"}
            // Disable the toggle on click while in review mode.
            disabled={isAccordionKeyDisabled}
          />
        </IonItem>
        {isToggleOpen && children}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

This scrolls the element into view, but if `children` contains a lot of text (for example, two screens' worth of text), the element that is scrolled into view won't be scrolled until it is at the top of the screen-- it could be halfway down the screen, or three-quarters; the placement seems a bit random.

**What I want to happen**: After clicking the toggle, I want the content to be expanded (`children` are shown with `isToggleOpen`) and then I want to scroll so that `scrollingRef` is at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your request " I want to scroll so that scrollingRef is at the top of the screen", I modified your code to have the desired behaviour.

```
import { useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

type MyProps = any;

export const WeirdAlAccordion: React.FC<MyProps> = ({ children }: MyProps) => {
  const scrollingRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [isToggleOpen, setIsToggleOpen] = useState(false);

  const scrollMyRef = () => {
    // Only scroll into view if it is being opened.
    if (!isToggleOpen && scrollingRef?.current !== null) {
      scrollingRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        block: "start",
        inline: "nearest",
      });
    }
  };
  const mimicChildren = useMemo(() => {
    const ChildrenBasicArray = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (value, index) => ({
      value: index,
      id: _.uniqueId(),
    }));
    return ChildrenBasicArray.map((item, index) => (
      <div
        key={item.id}
        style={{
          height: "120px",
          backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0 ? "red" : "blue",
        }}
      >
        {item.value}
      </div>
    ));
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: "300px" }}>fake element</div>
      <div style={{ height: "300px" }}>fake element</div>
      <div
        style={{
          height: isToggleOpen ? "600px" : "20px",
          width: "300px",
          overflow: isToggleOpen ? "scroll" : "visible",
          background: "#ccc",
        }}
        ref={scrollingRef}
        onClick={() => {
          setIsToggleOpen(!isToggleOpen);
          scrollMyRef();
        }}
      >
        {isToggleOpen && mimicChildren}
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: "300px" }}>fake element</div>
      <div style={{ height: "300px" }}>fake element</div>
      <div style={{ height: "300px" }}>fake element</div>
    </>
  );
};
```